# Using subprocess and .format

Tags: python, string

So I have this code so far:

```
from subprocess import call
a, b = 10000000, 10000100
call('samtools faidx file.fa chr22:{}-{}'.format(a, b), shell = True)
```

but when I run it, the numbers assigned to `a` and `b` does not seem to go into the `{}` brackets as format should do.
Am I using format wrong here, or is my code itself wrong?

(file.fa is a file that holds a DNA sequence for chromosome 22)

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: looks like python

Comment: @TallChuck Indeed, but you can never be so sure

Comment: Evaluating just `'samtools faidx file.fa chr22:{}-{}'.format(a, b)` in the Python REPL (after defining `a` and `b`) gives me `'samtools faidx file.fa chr22:10000000-10000100'`.  What makes you think the `format()` method isn't working here?

Comment: That said, this is prone to shell injection attacks -- if your `a` and `b` could be controlled by a hostile entity, they could run arbitrary code. Much safer not to use `shell=True`, but to `call(['samltools', 'faidx', 'file.fa', 'chr22:{}-{}'.format(a,b)])`.

Comment: @AndyLee, we'd need to know what `samtools faidx` does to know if that's correct behavior. Could you perhaps come up with a simpler reproducer? `a=100; b=200; __import__('subprocess').call(['printf', '<%s>\n', 'chr22:{}-{}'.format(a,b)])`, for example, doesn't require `samtools`, or anything else not already present on a POSIX platform, to run, and prints unambiguous content on stdout. Please see the docs on  building a [mcve].

Comment: samtools faidx is a command used in linux, where if i provide a fasta file (DNA sequence file) and sequence locations (100~200 for example), the system will print whatever letters are in the file in between the positions 100~200.
I used subprocess because I was told that by using that I can use commands in other operating systems (such as linux) in python

Comment: What OS are you using? I've had problems with `subprocess` on Windows

Comment: @MrJLP I am using windows as well

Comment: So you're on Linux? How do you know the number isn't going into the string? You can print out your string before the call() to verify

Comment: What OS is this problem happening on?

Comment: Put the command into a string and print out to verify it's correct. From what you have it looks like the format worked fine